# Compiling a shared object folder without libc

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, libc, shared-objects

Is it possible to build a shared object file on Linux without using libc? I tried building the shared object using -nostdlib, and it complains that there is a conflicting type for built-in function 'memset'(I have my own version of the function defined within the shared object I am trying to build).

I am not using any libc functions from within the shared object file. I am building the shared object as follows :-

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -nostdlib
OUTPUTDIR = ./build
test: outputdir
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -fPIC test.c -o ${OUTPUTDIR}/test.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ${OUTPUTDIR}/test.o -shared -o ${OUTPUTDIR}/libtest.so

outputdir:
    mkdir -p ${OUTPUTDIR}

clean:
    rm -rf ${OUTPUTDIR}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you link with `-nostdlib`, you should also compile with `-ffreestanding` and/or `-fno-builtin` as well.

You also have to be careful that you do not reference a `libc.so.6` symbol without linking against glibc.  Things may appear to work superficially, but it tends to introduce breakage in certain environments, especially once additional IFUNCs are added to glibc.  ([Intel did that with the ICC 16 compiler library.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compiler-version-16-not-compatible-with-recent-libcso6))